# Calculating convolution of two piecewise functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, convolution, signal-processing, piecewise-continuity

> Let $$x(t) =\begin{cases}2&-2\lt t \lt 0 \\ -2  &0\lt t \lt 1\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $$h(t) =\begin{cases}4(1-|t|)&|t|\le1 \\0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 
>   Compute $x*h=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(u)h(t - u)du$ .

Using graphical interpretation of convolution we get:

$$y(t) =\begin{cases}0&t \lt -3 \\ 4(t+3)^2  &-3\lt t \lt -2\\  -4(t^2+2t-1)  &-2\lt t \lt -1&   \\  -8t(t+2)  &-1\lt t \lt 0 \\ 12t^2-16t & 0 \lt t \lt 1\\-4(t-2)^2 &1 \lt t \lt 2 \\ 0 & t \gt 2  
\end{cases}$$ This answer was verified with Mathematica.

**My attempt:**

$$x*h=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t-u)h(u)du = \int_{-1}^1 x(t-u)h(u)du = \int_{-1}^1 4x(t-u)(1-|u|)du =\int_{-1}^0 4x(t-u)(1+u)du + \int_{0}^1 4x(t-u)(1-u)du = I_1 + I_2$$

Then we have
$$x(t-u) =\begin{cases}2&-2\lt t-u \lt 0 \\ -2  &0\lt t-u \lt 1\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

If we consider $I_1$ then $-1\lt u \lt 0$ and $I_2$ then $0\lt u \lt 1$. So there are two separate cases:
$$-1 \lt u \lt 0 \implies x(t-u) =\begin{cases}2&-3\lt t \lt 0 \\ -2  &-1 \lt t \lt 1\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and similarly 
$$0 \lt u \lt 1 \implies x(t-u) =\begin{cases}2&-2\lt t \lt 1 \\ -2  &0 \lt t \lt 2\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
then evaluating integrals leads to

$$I_1 =\begin{cases}4&-3\lt t \lt 0 \\ -4  &-1 \lt t \lt 1\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and

$$I_2 =\begin{cases}4&-2\lt t \lt 1 \\ -4  &0 \lt t \lt 2\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Is my calculations so far correct? If so, what's the next step? I don't understand why the values of the integrals are constant. They should be functions of $t$ to form such that solution.

Comment: $x(t - u) = -2 \hspace {1.5px} [t - 1 < u < t] + 2 \hspace {1.5px} [t < u < t + 2]$, so
$$\int_{-1}^0 x(t - u) f(u) du =
-2 \int_{[-1, 0] \cap [t - 1, t]} f(u) du +
 2 \int_{[-1, 0] \cap [t, t + 2]} f(u) du.$$
Then consider how the segments will overlap for different values of $t$. It might be simpler to use the (bilateral) Laplace transform, all the terms in $F(p)$ will have the form $e^{a p} p^b$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks, what do you mean by $x(t - u) = -2 \hspace {1.5px} [t - 1 < u < t] + 2 \hspace {1.5px} [t < u < t + 2]$ notation?

Comment: It's the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: @Maxim Would you please elaborate on $$\int_{-1}^0 x(t - u) f(u) du = -2 \int_{[-1, 0] \cap [t - 1, t]} f(u) du +  2 \int_{[-1, 0] \cap [t, t + 2]} f(u) du.$$ I think that explanation could be an answer so I can accept it